# Take panoramic photos in Android

Tags: android-studio, android-camera, photo, google-cardboard, 360-degrees

I want to make an Android application that allows the user to take panoramic pictures... I have been searching for several hours for some library or some sample code or tutorial but I didn't find anything very interesting. Some applications like "Cardboard camera" or the standard Android camera can do this! Is there a way to call these application functions? Or some API? It still would be good if the app I want to make just would use an external app to take the photo. Please help me, thank you :)

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried to understand the answer? I'm asking if there is a simple way to take a panoramic photo in my android app. I'm using Android Studio to make it. I want to put a button in the app that if you press it, a panoramic camera appears and you can take photos and edit this photos with some effects.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?